# Nothing is clickable in mobile view

Tags: magento-1.9, mobile

I have some serious trouble at the moment. For some reason, everything become non-clickable when viewing pages in mobile view.

For some reason, it only happens when the shown side has a sidebar, so I suspect it might have something to do with the mobile sidebar menu.

Live view of the problem: http://www.propagandashop.dk/belysning
(Change browser width until menu goes mobile)

ANY suggestions are really appreciated.. THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the culprit:

[image]

You should remove the 'pointer-events:none' line in modal.css

Edit:

Because the modal.css file is loaded from MailChimp, you won't be able to edit it indeed.

You can add the following to your shops css files:

```
html>body#bd {
  pointer-events: all !important;
}
```

This rule should be more specific than the one from MailChimp, and thus get preference over it.

Comment: Thank you so very, very much for your big help!! You totally saved my night from lots of sweating, crying and bleeding ;-)

As far as I can see, it comes from our mailchimp popup (mc-modal), but how on earth did it come to influence the whole page and not just the popup?

Comment: I wont! :-) I'm still a little troubled though, since the modal.css seems to come from mailchimp I dont think I can edit it. Should I override the css somehow? And do you have any idea how it came to influence my whole page and not just mailchimp popup?

Comment: I have edited the answer, can you please try that solution?

Comment: Thank you! I will start by disabling the popup entirely and contact mailchimp support. Something must be off since it can destroy my shop like that. If they can't help, I will use your solution instead. Thank you once again for your effort.